# Ajax getting 412 (Precondition Failed) sometimes

Tags: ajax, struts

I am writing a website with Struts and Tomcat as the server.

On a page there's an ajax post request using jQuery (not cross-domain). The returned value is plain html.

The problem is, I **sometimes** (not always, not even frequent) get 412 (Precondition Failed) error. What could be the cause of this unstable error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer because I've just had this issue today.  It's obviously an update to Mod Security in my case.

I was sending data to the server via AJAX and some Javascript which was part of this message caused the 412. It turned out to be the word HTML (I was passing element.innerHTML within the code)

ModSecurity treats that as a potential threat by the looks of it.  For a quick fix I replaced all HTML strings with H%T%M%L and reversed the process on the server and it's now running.

You've probably long-since solved this but posting in case it's useful for anyone else.

Comment: This is an ancient question but I still get this problem occasionally.. I've found POSTing html (not the word HTML) causes issues and if the < is replaced before the POST with something else and reversed at the server it gets through.

Answer (score 0):

Just today i was facing the same problem "412 Precondition Failed".

It is a Codeigntier app that uploads audio and Image files.

Till now a lot of files uploaded through the Ajax File uploader. But today i file was not uploading and through chrome Inspect > Network i found that error 412 Precondition Failed.

I re-uploaded the file so many file by changing my ajax script multiple times.

Suddenly some special character caught my attention. I renamed the file and tried to re-upload. Trust me it worked.

**Before:**
[image]

**AFTER:**
[image]

I don't have proper explanation but it works for me.

Thanks